# Force customers to update account information

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, import, customer-account

I am importing a couple of thousand customers into a Magento instance and would like to force my customers to check and update their account information upon logging in for the first time.
Is this possible in native Magento or is there an extension to do this job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a solution, it's just an idea.
Add a new customer attribute called `profile_updated`. This should be a yes/no flag.
Then create an observer on the event `controller_action_predispatch` (that is dispatched for all pages) where you check this:

- if the customer is not logged in, do nothing
- if the customer is logged in

  - if the action is "profile edit page" or "profile save action" do nothing
  - if the action is not one of the 2 above

    - if the flag `profile_updated` is `false` redirect the customer to his/her profile edit page
    - if the flag `profile_updated` is `true` do nothing

When the customer updates something set the flag `profile_updated` to `true`. For this you can observe the event `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_editpost`

You can check the current page like this:

```
$action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
```

the action for account edit is `customer_account_edit` and for save account info the action is `customer_account_editpost`.